# Disable the "Open Attribute Table" in ArcGIS for some raster layers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, spatial-analyst

I have made a layer using cell statistics (Spatial Analysis tool). I need to process the attributes before exporting the layer, however the open attribute table is disabled.

How to enable the table or use data?

The layer was converted to other formats including point. Its attribute table is opened while the field is grid code and the original needed field before cell statistics process is not available.

Comment: Cell statistics is for raster layer. Are you trying to open an attribute table of a raster layer because raster layer does not have an attribute table

Comment: Is your raster floating point or integer? Have you tried to build the [attribute table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/build-raster-attribute-table.htm)?

Comment: Only integer rasters can support an attribute table, and even then there's a limit on the number of discrete values.

Comment: @Vince Thank you. Is it possible to convert a floating point pixel to integer one?

Comment: I mean if the case of loosing data would not be problematic.

Comment: I tried Round up and round down to convert to integer. it did not work.

Answer (score -1):

As the layer is floating point, it is need to convert a floating point pixel to integer one. 
Round up and round down were tried to convert to integer. They did not work because the value were still floating.
Int (Spatial Analyst) converts each cell value of a raster to an integer by truncation. It did work.